# Alternative for displayFormat property for ion-datetime in Ionic 7

Tags: ionic5, ionic7

In Ionic 5 it was possible to customise time formats of ion-datetime using the property displayFormat. eg. <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" ....

In Ionic 7 this does not seem to be working any more. Instead, we should use locale property, e.g. ion-datetime locale="es-ES"

Is there any way to customise the time format for ion-datetime in Ionic 7? I need to be able to specify something like "HH:mm", "H:mm", etc.